# c++ program with set and get in class

Tags: c++

somewhere i went wrong what seems to be the problem? but this is what i was trying to do: i want to create an Employee class that includes these data members first name (type string), a last name (type string) and a monthly salary (type int, also a constructor that initializes the three data members, provide a set and a get function for each data member, If the monthly salary is not positive i want to set it to 0, create two Employee objects and display each object’s yearly salary, and to give each Employee a 20 percent raise and display each Employee’s yearly salary again

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Employee {

public:

Employee(string f ,string l ,int m ){
setFName(f) ;
setLName(l) ;
setMSalary(m) ;
}

void setFName(string f){
fName = f ;
}

string getFName(){
return  fName ;
}

void setLName(string l){
lName = l ;
}

string getLName(){
return lName ;
}

void setMSalary(int m){
if ( m <0 ){
mSalary = 0 ;
    }
else {
mSalary = m ;
    }
}

intgetMSalary(){
returnmSalary ;
}

intySalary(){
return12 * mSalary ;
}

 intraise(){
 return (0.10 * ySalary()) + ySalary() ;
 }

private :

string fName ;
string lName ;
int mSalary ;
 }; 



int main(){

Employeeem1("SARA" , "SALEH" , 5000);
Employeeem2("Bayan" , "Khaled" , 8000 ) ;

cout<<"The yearly salary of first employee is "<< em1.ySalary() <<endl ;
cout<<"The yearly salary of second employee is "<< em2.ySalary()<<endl ;

cout<<"\nThe yearly salary of first employee is after raising "<<em1.raise()<<endl ;

cout<<"The yearly salary of second employee is after raising "<<em2.raise() <<endl ;
}
```

also

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std ;

class Employee {

public:

Employee(string f ,string l ,int m ){
setFName(f) ;
setLName(l) ;
setMSalary(m) ;
}

void setFName(string f){
fName = f ;
}

string getFName(){
return fName ;
}

void setLName(string l){
lName = l ;
}

string getLName(){
return lName ;
}

void setMSalary(int m){
if ( m <0 ){
mSalary = 0 ;
    }
else {
mSalary = m ;
    }
}

int getMSalary(){
return mSalary ;
}

private :

string fName ;
string lName ;
intmSalary ;
};



int main(){

Employeeem1("SARA" , "SALEH" , 5000);
Employeeem2("Bayan" , "Khaled" , 8000 ) ;
int raise1 , raise2 ;

cout<<"The yearly salary of first employee is "<< em1.getMSalary()*12<<endl ;

cout<<"The yearly salary of second employee is "<< em2.getMSalary() *12<<endl ;

raise1 = (0.20 * em1.getMSalary()) + em1.getMSalary() ;
raise2 = (0.20 * em2.getMSalary()) + em2.getMSalary() ;

cout<<"\nThe yearly salary of first employee is after raising "<< raise1 * 12<<endl ;

cout<<"The yearly salary of second employee is after raising "<< raise*12<<endl ;
}
```

i get these errors

```
-------------------Configuration: Employee - Win32 Debug--------------------
Compiling...
Employee.cpp
C:\Users\afaq\Desktop\del\Employee.cpp(42) : warning C4183: 'intgetMSalary': member function definition looks like a ctor, but name does not match enclosing class
C:\Users\afaq\Desktop\del\Employee.cpp(46) : warning C4183: 'intySalary': member function definition looks like a ctor, but name does not match enclosing class
C:\Users\afaq\Desktop\del\Employee.cpp(50) : warning C4183: 'intraise': member function definition looks like a ctor, but name does not match enclosing class
C:\Users\afaq\Desktop\del\Employee.cpp(41) : error C2065: 'returnmSalary' : undeclared identifier
C:\Users\afaq\Desktop\del\Employee.cpp(45) : error C2065: 'return12' : undeclared identifier
C:\Users\afaq\Desktop\del\Employee.cpp(45) : warning C4552: '*' : operator has no effect; expected operator with side-effect
C:\Users\afaq\Desktop\del\Employee.cpp(49) : error C2065: 'ySalary' : undeclared identifier
C:\Users\afaq\Desktop\del\Employee.cpp(63) : error C2065: 'Employeeem1' : undeclared identifier
C:\Users\afaq\Desktop\del\Employee.cpp(64) : error C2065: 'Employeeem2' : undeclared identifier
C:\Users\afaq\Desktop\del\Employee.cpp(66) : error C2065: 'em1' : undeclared identifier
C:\Users\afaq\Desktop\del\Employee.cpp(66) : error C2228: left of '.ySalary' must have class/struct/union type
C:\Users\afaq\Desktop\del\Employee.cpp(67) : error C2065: 'em2' : undeclared identifier
C:\Users\afaq\Desktop\del\Employee.cpp(67) : error C2228: left of '.ySalary' must have class/struct/union type
C:\Users\afaq\Desktop\del\Employee.cpp(69) : error C2228: left of '.raise' must have class/struct/union type
C:\Users\afaq\Desktop\del\Employee.cpp(71) : error C2228: left of '.raise' must have class/struct/union type
C:\Users\afaq\Desktop\del\Employee.cpp(72) : warning C4508: 'main' : function should return a value; 'void' return type assumed
Error executing cl.exe.

Employee.exe - 11 error(s), 5 warning(s)
```

Comment: what is the exact problem?

Comment: I just checked the second code. You only have small space related syntax errors...

Comment: uhm. the one problem is that you are missing spacing in a few places. "Employeeem1" should be "Employee em1".. "return12" should be "return 12". Just look at the error messages, its what they tell you

Comment: You say you want to initialise the members, but you don't -. you leave them uninitialised and *then assign* them. That's bad style. Change your constructor to `Employee(string f ,string l ,int m ) : fName(f), lName(l), intmSalary(m) {}`. The idiom you have used here (calling helper set functions) is only useful for otherwise too complicated initialisations.

Comment: Please next time at least have a quick look at the error messages! The number between parentheses following the file name is the line number in that file where the error occurs. Several errors are trivial typos that you could have fixed yourself first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the syntax corrections for the second version. You only have minor space related problems... see inline comments

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std ;

class Employee
{

public:

    Employee(string f , string l , int m )
    {
        setFName(f) ;
        setLName(l) ;
        setMSalary(m) ;
    }
    void setFName(string f)
    {
        fName = f ;
    }
    string getFName()
    {
        return fName ;
    }
    void setLName(string l)
    {
        lName = l ;
    }
    string getLName()
    {
        return lName ;
    }
    void setMSalary(int m)
    {
        if ( m < 0 )
        {
            mSalary = 0 ;
        }
        else
        {
            mSalary = m ;
        }
    }
    int getMSalary()
    {
        return mSalary ;
    }

private :
    string fName ;
    string lName ;
    //you forgot space after int
    int mSalary ;
};

int main()
{
    //you forgot space after  Employee
    Employee em1("SARA" , "SALEH" , 5000);
    Employee em2("Bayan" , "Khaled" , 8000 ) ;
    int raise1 , raise2 ;

    cout << "The yearly salary of first employee is " << em1.getMSalary() * 12 << endl ;

    cout << "The yearly salary of second employee is " << em2.getMSalary() * 12 << endl ;

    raise1 = (0.20 * em1.getMSalary()) + em1.getMSalary() ;
    raise2 = (0.20 * em2.getMSalary()) + em2.getMSalary() ;

    cout << "\nThe yearly salary of first employee is after raising " << raise1 * 12 << endl ;
    // I think you meant raise2 instead of raise
    cout << "The yearly salary of second employee is after raising " << raise2 * 12 << endl ;
}
```

Comment: @jhjh Please accept the answer if it solved your question